# TableView didselectrow not pushing another view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to push from viewcontroller with tableview to another view with tableview too,

```js
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print("Clicke\(indexPath.row)")
        guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecAdsViewController") as? SecAdsViewController else { return }
        vc.data = data[indexPath.row]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

the code is looking good, storyboard id is correct too but it is not pushing when I click on the cell and no action, console response is good too
[image]

breakpoint has no issues!
[image]

my story board
[image]

Comment: add  the breakpoint in  this `vc.data = data[indexPath.row]` line and check

Comment: `else { return }` is `return` called? `self.navigationController?`: Do you have a `navigationController`? Is `self.navigationController?` nil?

Comment: ensure once are you emnbed your SecAdsViewController in navigationController

Comment: @Larme yes it is embeded to navigation Controller

Comment: @Jacob- embed your root controller into navigationcontroller or where u need embed with navigationcontroller, it will work

Comment: So `self.navigationController?` is nil? So how did you expect it to work? You can use `present(animated:completion:)`, but that's a modal presentation. It's up to you if you want a navigation controller or not. Depends on your UX/UI.

Comment: Wait. It's embedded, but how did you init your viewController? I'm not sure that's it's adding the navvc when init like that, the nav VC doesn't have a storyboard id. I'd instantiate the navvc with its storyboard id, and retrieve the SecAdsViewController then. But, don't you have a warning about unreachable viewcontrollers? I'd create a new storyboard for it. And then instantiate the initialVC which would have the nav vc.

Comment: @Larme a very good suggestion, I have created a new StoryBoard and named it Sections, is it possible to instantiate the view controller on the other storyboard with the data too?

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in the comment the best solution is to create a new storyboard.
Try this

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(named: "Sections", bundle: "nil")
guard let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecAdsViewController") as? SecAdsViewController else { return }
vc.data = data[indexPath.row]
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

This solution assumes you don't have a NavigationController in Sections storyboard, which is something you would not want in any case as you already have a NavigationController in the other storyboard.